# On-Prem Install without using yum command

Tags: installation, apigee

If datacenter doesn't allow commands like yum, rpm, is there an alternative way to do an on-prem install of OPDK?

Comment: This belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

They will actually have to install their own local yum repository -- this means building up a rpm repository outside the data center and then brining that into the data center. Then you point yum on the Apigee machine to the internal yum repository.

We have a couple clients who have done this (who probably don't want it advertised so contact me directly for who has done it this way).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup yum client and yum server. Yum client being the machine in the datacenter and yum server which is the machine from which you can pull all required repositories.

Yum will be used to download repositories for open ldap , postgres and qpid.

If for initial testing you are setting up an "sa" ( standalone) installation without analytics you would not require yum. ( If we use analytics all dependencies for analytics(postgres and qpid ) are installed via yum)